# Range Line component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

need to create some kind of range component in React, but couldn't really find anything similar.

I would like to create something similar to the thingymabobby on the image. The black dot, the thumb, will not be moved by the user. It's only to show if the black dot - the result - is within the range. What would be the way to create it? Simply a slider and block somehow the thumb? Or do you know a library that has a similar solution?

[image]

Comment: What is `49.0`? What is the green bar in relation to `49.0`? Need some more of the requirements.

Comment: 49 is the value. The green bar is being defined by the lower limit and the upper limit. The black dot is the representation of 49 on the scale (necessary to define min and max as well, so the scale would be accurate, let say the min value is 0 and max is 75 on the screen, but needs to be configurable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something along these lines. Some of the positioning might be able to be simplified with different CSS based on the design requirements that aren't fully known, but the general idea of capturing the relative sizing/positions is demonstrated.

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))

const { styled } = window
const Wrap = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
`
const Result = styled.span`
  color: #70C47E;
  font-weight: bold;
`
const Bar = styled.span`
 position: relative;
 height: 2px;
 border-top: 2px solid #EAEAEA;
 flex: 1;
 &::before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   left: ${({ lower, min, max }) => (lower - min) / max * 100}%;
   top: -5px;
   height: 8px;
   width: ${({ lower, upper, max }) => (upper - lower) / max * 100}%;
   background-color: rgba(112, 196, 126, 0.4);
 }
 &::after {
   content: '•';
   font-size: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   left: ${({ result, max }) => result / max * 100}%;
   top: -12px;
 }
`
const RangeLine = ({ min = 0, max = 75, lower = 25, upper = 75, result = 49 }) => {
  return (
    <Wrap>
      <Result>{result}</Result>
      <Bar result={result} lower={lower} upper={upper} max={max} min={min} />
    </Wrap>
  )
}


root.render(
  <div>
    <RangeLine />
    <RangeLine result={15} />
    <RangeLine result={65} upper={50} />
    <RangeLine result={25} min={0} max={100} lower={15} upper={45} />
  </div>
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-is/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

There is a more robust version of this published as [`react-meter-chart`](https://github.com/morganney/react-meter-chart).

Answer (score 1):

There's basically 2 questions here:

### Should you use a range input without allowing user interaction?

In most cases it's indeed best to use a disabled range input, as it still already has the right behavior and appearance.

At least from a technical point of view. For the UX it might be frustrating that a user sees a very user friendly component but can't use it and needs to type in a number field instead. But at least if you use a range input it's a small change to make it actually usable.

### How to show a range input with a "allowed sub range"

This can be useful regardless of whether the user can control the range input. It's relatively easy to achieve by doing some calculations on the input to render a square behind the input element.

Here's an example, though there could be some work left to adapt it to any CSS that happens to be on the same page, so that you can be sure the numbers line up correctly with the square.

If you don't intend to use the `onChange` handler you can remove it, but it won't cause problems to keep it either if the `disabled` attribute is on.

```js
const {Fragment, useState} = React;

function HighlightedSubrange({
  number,
  min,
  max,
  minAllowed,
  maxAllowed,
  disabled,
  onChange
}) {
  const length = max - min;
  const left = `${100 * (minAllowed - min) / length}%`;
  const right = `${100 * (max - maxAllowed) / length}%`;
  
  const value = number;
  
  return <div style={{position: 'relative', paddingTop: '4px', height: '24px', width: '320px'}}>
    <input
      type="range"
      {...{min, max, onChange}}
      value={value}
      disabled={disabled}
      style={{
        position: 'relative',
        zIndex: 4,
        width: '100%',
      }}
    />
    <div
      style={{
        zIndex: 3,
        background: 'hsl(148deg 56% 84%)',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left,
        right,
      }}
    />
  </div>
}

function Example() {
  const [min, setMin] = useState(0);
  const [minAllowed, setMinAllowed] = useState(50);
  const [maxAllowed, setMaxAllowed] = useState(80);
  const [max, setMax] = useState(100);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(75);
  
  return <Fragment>
    <input
      type="number"
      min={0}
      max={100}
      value={number}
      onChange={e=>setNumber(e.target.value)}
    />
    <HighlightedSubrange
      {...{number, min, max, minAllowed, maxAllowed, disabled}}
      onChange={e=>setNumber(e.target.value)}
    />
    <div style={{background: 'lightgrey', padding: '8px'}}>
      <h3>Props</h3>
      <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
        min<input
          type="number"
          value={min}
          onChange={e=>setMin(e.target.value)}
        />
        minAllowed<input
          type="number"
          min={min}
          max={maxAllowed}
          value={minAllowed}
          onChange={e=>setMinAllowed(e.target.value)}
        />
        maxAllowed<input
          type="number"
          min={minAllowed}
          max={max}
          value={maxAllowed}
          onChange={e=>setMaxAllowed(e.target.value)}
        />
        max<input
          type="number"
          value={max}
          onChange={e=>setMax(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={disabled} onClick={e=>setDisabled(!disabled)} readOnly/>disabled
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </Fragment>
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(<Example/>);
```

```css
input[type="number"] {
  max-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice idea, though about something like that myself, although a friend down below coded it perfectly in CSS. Thanks for your help nonetheless :)